# Plotting time series with R

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R and I've to plot 50 point. 
My input data are something like these:

```
Day             Pressure
20/01/2013 13:30:00     980
20/01/2013 20:30:00     978
21/01/2013 13:30:00     985
21/01/2013 20:30:00     991
```

I've some problems because I can't find the right command to plot the Day vs the Pressure.

Comment: That's because those first columns are character values and need to be converted to Dates or date-times. If this is from an R-object, ...perhaps an xts one? you should post output from `dput(object_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you plot the data using ggplot2.

The data I used was as follows:

```
Day             Pressure
20/01/2013 13:30:00 980
20/01/2013 20:30:00 978
21/01/2013 13:30:00 985
21/01/2013 20:30:00 991
```

The code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
data2 <- read.csv("Stack Overflow/timeseries.csv")
data2
data2$Day <- strptime(data2$Day, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
ggplot(data2, aes(x=Day, y=Pressure))+geom_point()+xlab("Date")
```

Hope it helps.

**Output**
[image]

If you want to use base plot then use the following:

```
plot(data2$Day,data2$Pressure, xlab="Date",ylab="Pressure")
```

Comment: If the answer helps you, would you upvote and accept the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) read the data into `z` and plot it:

```
Lines <- "Day             Pressure
20/01/2013 13:30:00 980
20/01/2013 20:30:00 978
21/01/2013 13:30:00 985
21/01/2013 20:30:00 991
"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, skip = 1, index = 1:2, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
plot(z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your "Day" column into Date format for that you need to use as.Date("column") conversion trick.
I took the same data as yours

and plotted it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWEuc.jpg here..(as i don't have enough reputation points).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

date_count<-read.csv("sample_date.csv")
timeline<-as.Date(date_count$Day)
df<-data.frame(timeline,date_count$Pressure)
date_count.tmp<-ggplot(df, aes(x=timeline, y=date_count$Pressure)) + geom_line() 


summary(date_count.tmp)
save(date_count,file="temp_tags_count.rData")
ggsave(file="sample_datecount.pdf")
ggsave(file="sample_datecount.jpeg",dpi=72)
```

and there you go with your problem solution.