# Convert Date attribute for time series plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataset, time-series, data-mining

I have a data set of the following form:

```
  Store Dept       Date Weekly_Sales IsHoliday
1     1    1 2010-02-05     24924.50     FALSE
2     1    1 2010-02-12     46039.49      TRUE
3     1    1 2010-02-19     41595.55     FALSE
4     1    1 2010-02-26     19403.54     FALSE
5     1    1 2010-03-05     21827.90     FALSE
6     1    1 2010-03-12     21043.39     FALSE
```

This data extends as:
There are **99 Dept** in each stores and there are **45 stores**. I wanted the data to be **split among individual Dept of individual Stores**. Hence the following code:

```
train<- read.csv("train.csv")  
splitData<-lapply(split(train,as.factor(train$Store)),FUN= function(x)split(x,x$Dept) )
```

Now, `splitData[[1]][1][[1]]` contains the tuples corresponding to 1st Dept of 1st store.

I need to **plot the graph** of *date vs Weekly_Sales*. So, I used the method mentioned in the accepted method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045177/plotting-time-series-with-r) and did:

```
splitData[[1]][1][[1]]$Date <- strptime(splitData[[1]][1][[1]]$Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

But to my surprise, the Date form got converted into **NA** values. Following is a snapshot of data:

```
  Store Dept Date Weekly_Sales IsHoliday
1     1    1 <NA>     24924.50     FALSE
2     1    1 <NA>     46039.49      TRUE
3     1    1 <NA>     41595.55     FALSE
4     1    1 <NA>     19403.54     FALSE
5     1    1 <NA>     21827.90     FALSE
6     1    1 <NA>     21043.39     FALSE
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong and the correct method to do so?

Comment: `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`? Also Kaggle has rules about sharing code outside of their forums...

Comment: @JakeBurkhead...thanks for the help...and I didn't know about the rules...will keep it within the forums now